# Python calling script without waiting for it to execute

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I want to know if there is any way to call a python script and just completely start that programe in a different thread so the main programe (caller) does not have to wait till the called script finishes executing. So far I've tried subprocess, and os.system but both of these two lag on until the script finishes executing.

## main.py

```
os.system('"F:\second.py"')
//continue the rest of the code without waiting for second.py to finish
```

## second.py

```
//do stuff
```

Comment: Like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221947/python-threads-with-os-system-calls-main-thread-doesnt-exit-on-ctrlc?

Comment: Im not quite sure @StephenRauch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

first.py

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["python.exe", "second.py"])
print "done"
```

second.py

```
import time
for i in range(10):
    print i
    time.sleep(10)
```

EDIT:

if you want to completly seperate the first and the second script add a flag

first.py

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["python.exe", "second.py"], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
print "done"
```

Comment: subprocess.Popen waits for `second.py` to complete, this isnt what im looking for  :/

Comment: It does for me (windows/ python 2.7). If you want, you can also add a flag and open the subprocess in a separate window (see my edits in the answer)

Comment: It works, do you know how to pass extra parameters to second.py with this method?

Comment: Just add them to the first argument  list as separate strings ["python.exe", "second.py", "param1", "param2"]

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Unix machine, you can use [`os.fork()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fork) to create a separate  process that will continue running even when the parent process has finished. For example:

**main.py**

```python
import os

pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0: # pid is only equal to 0 in the child process
    os.system('python second.py')
```

**second.py**

```python
import time

time.sleep(2)
print("I'm a child process!")
```