# Page won't load until program is closed

Tags: python

I am making an API to launch apps from my phone to my pc but when I access the route to the API the page won't load until the program launched with `os.system()` is closed

Here is my code:

```
import os
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    os.system("notepad")
    return "<p>Hello, World!<br>Launching Notepad!</p>"
```

Thanks in advance for the help!
Ps.: I am new to flask and APIs in general.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48252631/python-calling-script-without-waiting-for-it-to-execute

Comment: That's probably because the opened program blocks further execution of the view. Take a look, for example, at https://stackoverflow.com/a/27625288/4183498.

Answer (score 1):

`os.system` [does not return](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) until the process it started has exited.

Take a look at the [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) to start processes in the background. In the simplest case:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("notepad")
```