# After calling NotePad++ using subprocess, Python won't start executing other codes until I close the Notepad program

Tags: python, subprocess, notepad++

I am trying to open a .txt file using NotePad++ in Python IDE using `subprocess.call` function. One issue I needed help is that once I execute below codes:
 `subprocess.call([r"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe", r"C:\location\myfile.txt"])`
Python won't start executing other codes untiless I close the Notepad++ program. I have to use Ctrl+C to stop it.
What I am trying to do here is to open a file and view it, but I need my code to continue running other functions instead of wait for me to close the NotePad++ program. Does anyone know how to solve it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:
[Python-calling-script-without-waiting-for-it-to-execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48252631/python-calling-script-without-waiting-for-it-to-execute)

You should use

```
subprocess.Popen
```

instead of

```
subprocess.call
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Popen can help to solve my problem.